# Unix: Batch move files from multiple subdirectories up 1 level

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, directory, batch-processing

How can I move files from several subdirectories up 1 level in one terminal command?

**File Structure:**
path/to/files/A/remove/image.png
path/to/files/B/remove/image.png
path/to/files/C/remove/image.png
path/to/files/D/remove/image.png
path/to/files/E/remove/image.png

**Desired Structure:**
path/to/files/A/image.png
path/to/files/B/image.png
path/to/files/C/image.png
path/to/files/D/image.png
path/to/files/E/image.png

There are A LOT of directories and each "letter" directory above includes several images.  **Also, would like to delete the directory the files were moved from.**

Comment: Why does it need to be done in a single command?  Is the Return key dodgey?

Comment: I don't understand your question... There are a lot of directories with a lot of files.  I just want the files moved up one level in each subdirectory.  It will take a long time to do it 1 directory at a time.

Comment: You specified "one terminal command" and I'd like to know why.

Comment: I believe my last comment answered that.  Any reasonable solution would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question...

Using the example directories in my original question, I used this command:

```
for a in $(find path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -type d); do mv $a/remove/* $a/; rmdir $a/remove; done
```

"remove" is the name of the subdirectory I wanted to move the files out of within each directory.

The answer was actually found here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/405146/how-to-mass-move-files-one-directory-up

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement (on a mac) but in my case the subdirectory did not have the same name as in the original question making it a bit more complicated. This is what worked for me:

from the "path/to" folder I ran

```
find .  -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f | awk -v sq="'" -F "/" '{print "mv -i " sq $0 sq " " sq  "./" $2 sq}' > moveup.sh
```

and then

```
sh moveup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

This moves all files to their grand-parent directory:

```
$ find path/to/files -type f -exec mv {} $(dirname $(dirname {})) \;
```

You add a `-name \*.type` or whatever, instead of the `-type f` option, in order to be more specific.

This removes empty directories:

```
$ find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

(although it generates benign errors, which I guess is because the directory structure has been altered while `find` is still working).

Comment: So, this doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for.  This moves everything up 2 directories...

If you see the example directories above..., this method moves all the files into path/to/files/ 

I want the files to remain in their individual directories, but to move out of a superfluous additional subdirectory. 

This answer would work if I ran it on each individual directory, but my question is how I can do a batch of all directories within path/to/files/